# 5 Distinct non-negative integers who's sum is 51. Prove for every solution there is always one sub-set of size 4 who's sum is at least 42.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-number-theory

Suppose $X = \begin{Bmatrix}
x_{1}, & x_{2}, & x_{3}, & x_{4}, & x_{5}
\end{Bmatrix}$ is a set of 5 distinct non-negative integers, with a set-sum of $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} = 51$

Show for all solutions of X there is a at least one sub-set of size 4 that has a sum of at least 42.

Also, how many different solutions are there for X, where order doesn't matter.
For example, {1, 2, 3, 4, 42} is not a different solution from {42, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

I'm just a bit stuck on some of these questions for university at the moment, we were given an example solution, to the main question, which is the sub-set one.

But I feel like it wasn't the best proof. Also I'm having a hard time figuring out how you would find out how many different solutions there are, if order doesn't matter. I was using "stars and bars" earlier to figure it out if order did matter.

Comment: You need to use the generalised pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the subset problem, notice that we can find a subset of 4 with sum 42 if the smallest number is 9 or less (since then we take all the other numbers). Yet it's impossible for the smallest number to be 10 (or larger), since then the minimum sum is

$$10+11+12+13+14=60$$

Therefore, the smallest number is at most 9, and the result follows.

For the other problem, here's a hint that'll help if you can count the ordered solutions: since all the numbers in an ordered solution are distinct, there are exactly $5! = 120$ ordered solutions per unordered solution. Problem is, you can't use stars and bars directly, since stars and bars doesn't necessarily give you *distinct* nonnegative integers. You'll have to do some casework to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you brother, it has been a long time. But I still remember the first time I asked this. Your answer was really helpful back then, and I still remember it to this day.